# Change back to Hotmail from Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

I have been changed from Hotmail to Outlook.com and I am not satisfied with the new webmail system.  Is there any way that I can switch back to Hotmail from this new Outlook.com service?

Comment: @Rita: You realize that we're not Microsoft, right? Maybe you should review our [FAQ] and our [about](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/about) page.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no longer an option to switch back to Hotmail.

> **Why can't I switch back to Hotmail?**
>
> Over time, Hotmail will be phased out and Outlook.com will be the free email service from Microsoft. As part of this transition, we've removed the option to switch back to Hotmail.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/outlook/auto-upgrade-outlook-FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

### Reverting back to Hotmail

You can simply revert back to the old Hotmail experience using the settings menu.

1. Click the settings icon in the top right.
2. Click "Switch Back to Hotmail" from the menu that appears.
3. The site will ask you whether you want to send feedback or not.  Click whichever you prefer
4. You will be redirected to the old Windows Live Experience.  Just click "Hotmail" at the top to see your Hotmail inbox.

[image: Settings Icon -> "Switch Back to Hotmail"]

### Switching to Outlook.com

If you wish to use the new Outlook.com mail service, this can be done in a similar way:

1. Click "Settings"
2. Click "Upgrade to Outlook.com"

[image: Settings -> "Upgrade to Outlook.com"]

Comment: This option is no longer available.

Comment: @AlEverett It was at the time of writing this.  It's a shame they removed the option.